# How to fix a messed Excel sheet and make a proper format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, script, automation, spreadsheet

I have a problem in a specific sheet: I need only country,network,NetworkName and currency columns, but in sheet all messed up. As you can see in network Colum there are name and MCCMNC code also same in network name Colum so basically I need to separate all data and make proper format by switching places between the content of the following columns: "Network" and "NetworkName" from line 14. Please refer to the following screenshots to explain more the situation:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Comment: create two helper columns where, using formulas, you insert the correct data. Then copy/paste-values over the original.

Answer (score 0):

A different, "low-tech" solution is to do it by hand, but not the hard way.

First, does the current order of rows matter? If so, add a helper column, perhaps before all of them so it's a new column A, and fill it with sequential numbers, 1 to whatever, so when all the sorting is said and done, you can sort on it to restore the current order, then delete the column.

Then, or immediately if that is not an issue, sort everything on one of the suspect columns, C or E. It's that simple because the data that is mixed is numerical for one bit, and alpha strings for the other. So wrong data will sort to the top of the list, or the bottom. Say you picked column C to sort on. After sorting all the bad entries into a single batch at the top (the bad ones in column C are numerical), insert a helper column, then copy and paste all the bad ones into the exact same rows in the helper column. Then go to the other column, E in this case, and copy all the good entries. Paste them in the corresponding place in column C. Copy the ones you first put in the helper column and paste them into the corresponding place in column E. Those places match, by the way, so there's no worry about more rows in one than the other. Finally, delete that helper column. Resort to restore order if that was important and delete that helper column.

I say "low-tech" cause there's no formulas, no nothing too complicated. That is because the data is so clearly easy to sort into a single batch. Were it to be a bit more mixed, it would be tougher because you'd have to eye it for batches that need moving like the above, and do each complete set before moving on. In that case, as the wrong data became harder to spot, you know, like 30 batches, not one like here, or 3-4-5 batches, not only would the work involved start to be onerous, but you would run the chance of goofing up... better and better chance of it...

However, formulas would have to be tuned to match each batch... and data combed over and over to make sure you haven't missed any batches you didn't anticipate... it's hard and error-prone too, depending on the data and how well you can find useful patterns in it.

In this case, this is faster and better. In another case, that's a tougher call. Way tougher. You could use both methods, this one for, say, 80% and formulas for the rest. Pick the low hanging fruit the easy way, then do the rest.